# Javascript plugin DRY

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have written a Backbone View (javascript) for a component called "twist-panel".

A twist panel is basically a card flip, it has a front and back side, and can flip to the back and to the front.

Here is the code:

```
var TwistPanel = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.$front = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-front');
    this.$back = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-back');

    this.atFront = true;
    this.isFlipping = false;

    // Fix the height of the twist panel container.
    this.$el.height(this.$front.outerHeight(true));
  },
  toBack: function() {
    var self = this;

    if (this.isFlipping || !this.atFront) return;

    // Fix height.
        this.$el.height(this.$back.outerHeight(true));

        this.$front.afterTransition(function() {
            self.atFront = false;
            self.isFlipping = false;
            self.trigger('twist', 'back');
        });

        this.isFlipping = true;
        this.$el.addClass('twist');
  },
    toFront: function(callback) {
            var self = this;

        if (this.isFlipping || this.atFront) return;

        // Fix height.
        this.$el.height(this.$front.outerHeight(true));

        this.$back.afterTransition(function() {
            self.atFront = true;
            self.isFlipping = false;
            self.trigger('twist', 'front');
        });

        this.isFlipping = true;
        this.$el.removeClass('twist');
    }
});
```

As you can see in the code above, there is a lot of code duplication.
I would really appreciate some help on getting the code DRY.

Comment: `var self = this;` seems to be missing in toFront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way I approach the problem is by asking: what *does* change?

- `self.atFront` is flipped: not an issue here, you can simply write `self.atFront = !self.atFront`.
- conditions using `atFront` vs. `!atFront` (not an issue: if we factorize everything, we don't need to know what the state is: we just want to change it)
- the string in `self.trigger`
- `$front` vs. `$back`
- `removeClass()` vs. `addClass()`.

Quite a lot of things change, actually! At this point, we don't know yet if avoiding duplication is worth it: it often leads to more complicated code and it can be longer, too. But let's try it. I took your code, created a `flip` function, and tried to see what could fit in it. When writing this, I realized that it was simpler to put everything in the `flip` function, so I tried it:

```
var TwistPanel = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.$front = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-front');
    this.$back = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-back');

    this.atFront = true;
    this.isFlipping = false;

    // Fix the height of the twist panel container.
    this.$el.height(this.$front.outerHeight(true));
  },
  flip: function() {
    var self = this;
    var otherSide = ... ? this.$back : this.$front;

    if (this.isFlipping) return;

    this.$el.height(otherSide.outerHeight(true));

    this.$front.afterTransition(function() {
         self.isFlipping = false;
         self.trigger('twist', otherSide.name);
    });

    this.isFlipping = true;
    if (this.$el.hasClass('twist')) {
        this.$el.removeClass('twist')) {
    } else {
        this.$el.addClass('twist');
    }
  }
});
```

(I don't know about your application, but I guess `toFront` can never be called when we're already in front. If it's not true, then we need to keep `toFront` and `toBack` which will call `flip` themselves.)

At this point, I have two big issues left: I don't know how to decide what is the other side, and I don't know how to get its name (`otherSide.name`, used in the `self.trigger()` call). Since I don't know about this, I decided to resolve another issue, even if it is minor. This issue is that the `removeClass/addClass` logic looks wrong. It would probably be simpler to use something that is more than a value, and HTML5 data-* attributes are perfect for this since they are key-value and supported by jQuery. You can then replace the last five lines by this single one:

```
this.$el.data('twist', otherSide.name);
```

`$el` will either contain `data-twist="front"` or `data-twist="back"`: you then need to change your CSS to account for this minor change. What's nice here is that it's now possible to get the string you're interested in (`front` or `back`). And it's also easy to assign `otherSide`. We'll use jQuery `data()` for this. Here's the final untested code:

```
var TwistPanel = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.$front = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-front');
    this.$back = this.$el.find('.twist-panel-side-back');

    this.isFlipping = false;

    // Fix the height of the twist panel container.
    this.$el.height(this.$front.outerHeight(true));
  },
  flip: function() {
    var self = this;
    var otherSide = this.$el.data('twist') === 'front' ? this.$back : this.$front;
    var otherSideName = this.$el.data('twist') === 'front' ? 'back' : 'front';

    if (this.isFlipping) return;

    this.$el.height(otherSide.outerHeight(true));

    this.$front.afterTransition(function() {
         self.isFlipping = false;
         self.trigger('twist', this.$el.data('twist'));
    });

    this.isFlipping = true;
    this.$el.data('twist', otherSideName);
  }
});
```